# angular 2 user can do one click on the button then it becomes disabled

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Hello i am developing angular 2 app ;
I have entity article(id , title , text , vote) , account(id) , likes(articleid and userid) 
I have a button called like .
I want if the user click on the button like the button becomes disabled and vote increase .
I did a bit of code that works but the button is not disabled .
this is my function in the typescript side :

```
Like(Article,likes:Likes) {

    Article.vote += 1;
    this.articleService.modifier(Article)
        .subscribe((res: Article) => this.onSaveSuccess(res), (res: 
    Response) => this.onSaveError(res.json()));

   this.likes= new Likes;
   this.likes.articleid=Article.id;
    this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
        this.currentAccount = account;
    });
    this.likes.userid=this.currentAccount.firstName;
    this.likesService.create(this.likes)
        .subscribe((res: Likes) => this.onSaveSuccess2(res), (res:  
    Response) => this.onSaveError(res.json()));
}
```

This is the HTML side :

```
   <span *ngFor="let article of articles ;trackBy: trackId">
   <div style="margin-left: 30px; padding-top: 20px;">
   <div class="row">
   <h3 >{{article.titre}}</h3><br/>
   <p >{{article.text}}</p><br/>
   <div  > <strong >Publié par</strong><p >{{article.utilisateur}}</p></div>




   <p style="float:right;padding-right: 50px;margin-left: 5px;">    
     {{article.vote}}</p>

<span *ngFor="let likes of likess ;trackBy: trackId">

  <span *ngIf="likes.articleid === article?.id &&
                   likes.userid === account.id">

         <button type= "submit"
                 (click)=" Like(article,likes)"
                 disabled

                 class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>

                    </button>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="likes.articleid != article?.id || !likes.articleid  ">

         <button type= "submit"
                 (click)=" Like(article,likes)"


                 class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></span>

                    </button>
    </span>

</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicked on button set any property to true like `Article.disabled = true` and add the disabled directive on button like `[disabled]="article.disabled"`.

Comment: @Pengyy's answer is right but in that case using the single disableBtn will disable all the buttons at once. But if you have multiple articles and every article has its own like button then you need to set a property within article item like mentioned above

Comment: Yes but this will not saved at the database even i add an attribute called disable there is another problem that other users will not be able to click the button

Comment: No it will not be saved in database. It will be just for the front-end. But while fetching again from server you can check if the current logged in user has liked this article then for this specific element set the disable property to true and Angular will then automatically display the button as disabled.

Comment: Ok but how will i check if the current user logged has liked or not , and if he was the button should be disabled when i check the page for the first time.

Comment: You will simply query the table where you store the users likes (like which user has liked which article). This information will definitely be there in your db.

Comment: Ok i will try it , if it doesn't work i will inform you and if you can write me an answer that i can validate it

Comment: Sure you can ask me anytime.

Comment: i did it it worked but i doesn't know the query that will stored it

Comment: i want the query to know if the current user press like or not

Comment: These database related tasks which involves table structure and queries cannot be discussed here in comments. :)